# How can I change default "author" in npm?

Tags: npm

Every time I create new npm project, there is wrong author name, can I change it?

```sh
package name: (template) template
version: (1.0.0)
description:
entry point: (index.js) bot.js
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
license: (ISC)
About to write to:

{
  "name": "template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "*wrong author*",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can run following command

```
npm config set init-author-name "your name"
```

or go to package.json file and edit the author name.

```
 package name: (template) template
    version: (1.0.0)
    description:
    entry point: (index.js) bot.js
    test command:
    git repository:
    keywords:
    license: (ISC)
    About to write to:

    {
      "name": "template",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "bot.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Rajneesh Shukla",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using `npm init -y` to initialize your `package.json` and you're looking to have your own specified value for the `package.json#author` filled in by default.

Npm uses a couple configuration values to fill in that field: `init-author-name`, `..-email`, and `...-url`.

*Note, historically these confguration options used `.` instead of `-`.

**Dots (`.`) are [now deprecated](https://github.com/npm/statusboard/issues/535)** and will print a [confusing](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5302) warning if used.*

Per [the Npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc), these configuration values can be set in a couple places:

- per-project config file (`/path/to/my/project/.npmrc`)
- per-user config file (`~/.npmrc`)
- global config file (`$PREFIX/etc/npmrc`)
- npm builtin config file (`/path/to/npm/npmrc`)

So you can check those files to see if `init-author-*` *(or `init.author.*`)* are set.

Alternatively, you should be able to just set the configuration values as desired:

```bash
npm config set init-author-name  "your name"
npm config set init-author-email "your-email@example.com"
npm config set init-author-url   "https://my-domain/user"
```

This should result in the desired `package.json` configuration:

```json
{
    // ...
    "author": "your name <your-email@example.com> (https://my-domain/user)",
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dashes:

```
npm config set init-author-name "author's name"
```

Comment: This is actually the un-deprecated way of setting this value. Npm deprecated using dot separators in favor of dashes.